# How to visually consume/create .diff .patch files in OS X?

Tags: diff

Sorry, I'm just not finding anything that can do this!  For example I get a big fat .diff of 30 files.. sure, I can use `patch` and apply that to my source baseline.  But, I'd hope to be able to take that .diff and my source tree and interactively view those changes to review the diff and optionally merge in or ignore sections.

Comment: Did you ever find a decent solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `opendiff` which is part of Mac OS X Developer Tools (XCode).  It won't work exactly how you want (directly on .diff files), but you can make a temp copy of your source tree, apply your diffs, then run opendiff to compare visually.  You can then selectively merge and choose which version of each change to include.

Answer (score -1):

I use "p4merge" from Perforce.  It's commercial software, but this particular piece of the tool suite is free and available here on multiple platforms:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/downloads/

I think you have to download the whole visual client and then pull the pieces you want from the DMG.

Comment: I tried this and I don't see how I can load a .diff file up in it to diff against an existing tree.. maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: It's not the best for your use case, but a very useful tool.  I posted another answer that may be closer to what you're looking for.