# How to merge existing diff output?

Tags: unix, diff

Are there any tools where I can merge existing diff output?

The specific case is that git merge conflicts produces files with diff markers. For our specific process, these files with diff markers are checked in to be resolved later. So far we have always been resolving these merges by hand. I would like to know if there are any tools to make this easier.

This other question seems related, but there's no answer to it.

[How to visually consume/create .diff .patch files in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209138/how-to-visually-consume-create-diff-patch-files-in-os-x)